# How do you schedule execution of a Windows Workflow?

Tags: workflow, scheduled-tasks, workflow-foundation-4, schedule

I'd like to move my scheduled tasks into workflows so I can better monitor their execution. Currently I'm using a Window's scheduled task to call a web service that starts the process. Is there a facility that you use to schedule execution of a sequence so that it occurs every N minutes?

My optimal solution would:

- Easy to configure
- Provide useful feedback on errors
- Be 'fire and forget'

PS - Trying out AppFabric for Windows Server if that adds any options.

Comment: self-plug; http://powerwf.com has a built-in agent/scheduler and does workflow. Save your workflows as .xoml and load them up directly or import the compiled workflow dlls (will come in as single activities). Use PowerWF to deploy the workflow to the local agent on a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way I know of would be to make an executable for each workflow (could be console or windows app), and have it host the workflow through code.

This way you can continue to use scheduled tasks to manage the tasks, the main issue is feedback/monitoring the process.  For this you could output to console, write to the event log, or even have a more advanced visualisation with a windows app - although you'd have to write this yourself (or google for something!).  [This MS Workflow Monitoring sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741706.aspx) might be of interest, haven't used it myself.

Similar deal with errors, although writing to the event log would be the normal course of action in this case.

I'm not aware of any other hosts for WF, aside from things like Dynamics CRM, but that won't help you with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scheduler. Either roll your own, use AppFabic as mentioned or use Quartz.NET:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

If you use Quartz, it's either roll your own service host or use the ready-made one and configure it using xml. I rolled my own and it worked fine.

Comment: Is there a scheduling component in AppFabric?

Answer (score 0):

Autorun is another free option... http://autorun.codeplex.com/